# C - multiple warnings "pointer is missing a nullability type specifier" when compiling program, what do I do?

Tags: c, macos, clang, stdio, macos-catalina

I recently started having problems with compiling C programs, getting 10, 20 or 100 warnings from the different C packages like **stdio.h** or **stdlib.h**.

The warnings differ somewhat but usually say something like this:

```c
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:93:16: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or
      _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        unsigned char   *_base;
```

My program still compiles and works fine, but I worry that this needs to be fixed and also it is extremely annoying getting all these warnings in the terminal.

I am almost certain these warnings started showing after I updated my system to macOS Catalina but I don't know where to begin to solve it.

More concretely, when I compile a simple **helloworld.c** program like so

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    printf("Hello World!"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

with the following commands:

```c
make helloworld
```

or

```c
gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

..I get the following warnings, even though the program actually compiles.

```c
In file included from helloworld.c:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdio.h:64:
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:93:16: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        unsigned char   *_base;
                        ^
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:93:16: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        unsigned char   *_base;
                        ^
                          _Nullable 
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:93:16: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        unsigned char   *_base;
                        ^
                          _Nonnull 
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:138:32: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:138:32: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nullable
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:138:32: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:138:40: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                                  ^
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:138:40: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                                  ^
                                                   _Nullable
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:138:40: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                                                  ^
                                                   _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:139:35: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        fpos_t  (* _Nullable _seek) (void *, fpos_t, int);
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:139:35: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        fpos_t  (* _Nullable _seek) (void *, fpos_t, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nullable
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:139:35: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        fpos_t  (* _Nullable _seek) (void *, fpos_t, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:140:32: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                          ^
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:140:32: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nullable
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:140:32: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                          ^
                                           _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:140:46: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:140:46: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                                        ^
                                                         _Nullable
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:140:46: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        int     (* _Nullable _write)(void *, const char *, int);
                                                        ^
                                                         _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:144:18: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
        struct __sFILEX *_extra; /* additions to FILE to not break ABI */
                        ^
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:144:18: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
        struct __sFILEX *_extra; /* additions to FILE to not break ABI */
                        ^
                          _Nullable 
/usr/local/include/_stdio.h:144:18: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
        struct __sFILEX *_extra; /* additions to FILE to not break ABI */
                        ^
                          _Nonnull 
In file included from helloworld.c:1:
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:67:13: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
extern FILE *__stdinp;
            ^
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:67:13: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
extern FILE *__stdinp;
            ^
              _Nullable 
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:67:13: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
extern FILE *__stdinp;
            ^
              _Nonnull 
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:41: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:41: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                        ^
                                         _Nullable
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:41: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                        ^
                                         _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:55: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                                      ^
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:55: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                                      ^
                                                       _Nullable
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:55: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *, const char *, int),
                                                      ^
                                                       _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:387:44: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 fpos_t (* _Nullable)(void *, fpos_t, int),
                                           ^
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:387:44: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 fpos_t (* _Nullable)(void *, fpos_t, int),
                                           ^
                                            _Nullable
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:387:44: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 fpos_t (* _Nullable)(void *, fpos_t, int),
                                           ^
                                            _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:388:41: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *));
                                        ^
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:388:41: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *));
                                        ^
                                         _Nullable
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:388:41: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
                 int (* _Nullable)(void *));
                                        ^
                                         _Nonnull
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:384:6: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
FILE    *funopen(const void *,
        ^
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:384:6: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
FILE    *funopen(const void *,
        ^
          _Nullable 
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:384:6: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
FILE    *funopen(const void *,
        ^
          _Nonnull 
13 warnings generated.
```

EDIT: [Mike Minaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1624275/mike-minaev) provided a temporary fix that I am using for now. Command:

```c
gcc -Wno-nullability-completeness helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

EDIT: I have looked around and tried various solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58349403/15168) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539285/pointer-is-missing-a-nullability-type-specifier), including reinstalling xcode with CLI but without results.

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) below speculates that it could be because my header files are located in `usr/local/include`instead of `usr/include` but no fix is suggested.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201058/discussion-on-question-by-lazeauzwelt-c-multiple-warnings-pointer-is-missing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

temp quick fix for me:

```
gcc -Wno-nullability-completeness file.c
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran `gcc -Wno-nullability-completeness file.c -o file` to compile and then `./file` to run in my terminal. No warnings appeared, lovely. 

Question, any specific reason you left out `-o file`?

Comment: no, `a.out` if fine for me. Also if you use `pthread` library you need to add `-Wno-expansion-to-defined`